# Before migrating, can we get a grace period to discuss where the posts should be going?

Tags: discussion

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43976/question-on-galois-theory

This question was migrated to matheducators SE, when it should have been migrated to math SE.

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7937/question-on-galois-theory

I feel like we should spend a bit more time making sure we migrate to the right place once; if we don't, then we just kick the can to the next Stack Exchange to have a bunch of users and a moderator on that SE close/migrate again.

Comment: aeismail can speak for himself, but I'm pretty sure this was just a mistake in the migration. Matheducators is clearly the wrong destination for this site. I don't think policy is needed to fix what was probably just aeismail's not being aware that the matheducators site even existed.

Comment: See below. It was indeed just an accident.

Answer (score 3):

The migration to Mathematics Educators was an accident resulting from trying to do something on a different device than I normally use. I meant to put it into Mathematics (where it has now been sent), but "Mathematics Educators" was selected. I tried to delete "Educators," thinking the system would be smart enough to see the match with "Mathematics," but apparently it's not. You actually have to select it from a dropdown (which is a complete mess on the mobile interface).

Comment: I'm fine with it being an accident, but according to [Nate Eldridge](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7937/question-on-galois-theory#comment16421_7937), it would be unsuitable for migration to mathematics as well, as it doesn't meet their guidelines, as it is homework help. If it's a bad question for the place we want to move it to, then moving it there isn't helping that Stack Exchange either. It's a primary reason why Stack Overflow no longer migrates anything to Code Review, because most of the stuff moved ended up not meeting CRSE requirements either.